# computing expectation when you have 3 probability density functions

Tags: probability

You are given 3 separate pdfs and that $X = 1$ has a $5\%$ chance of happening, $X = 2$ has a $3\%$ chance of happening, and $X=3$ has a $92\%$ chance of happening.

Let $Y$’s probability density function be ($y \geq 0$):

$f(y) = 5e^{-5y}$ when $X = 1$

$f(y) = 11e^{-11y}$ when $X = 2$

$f(y) = 0$ when $X = 3$

What would  $E(Y)$ be? Im a bit confused because if you just have a pdf on its own then $E(Y)$ would simply be $E(Y) = $$\int_{0}^{\infty} xf(x) dx$.

Would it be a weighted Expected value? Something like $E(Y) = 0.92E(Y, X = 3) + 0.03E(Y, X = 2) + 0.05E(Y, X = 1)$

Comment: Yes, it's just the weighted average of the three expectations.

Comment: I guess you mean $Y$ has one distribution with probability $0.05$, a second distribution w.p. $0.03$ and $Y=0$ w.p. $0.92$. In this setup there is no 'density' of $Y$.

Comment: @lulu Does the same apply for Variance? If I wanted Var(Y) would it be $Var(Y) = 0.29Var(,=3) + 0.03Var(,=2)+0.05Var(,=1)$?

Comment: No.  You have to recompute the variance using the new mean.  Shouldn't be difficult though.  To gain insight, try it with discrete distributions first.

Comment: @lulu Sorry I am a bit confused. Based on what you said, I want to start of with  $Var[Y] = E[(Y-E[Y])^2]$. But i'm not sure how to proceed from that point. I do have $E[Y]$, but how would I compute $(E[(Y-E[Y])^2]$?

Comment: Just compute the variance from the definition, $\int (x-\mu)^2\,dx$.  Of course, you already have values for $\int (x_i-\mu_i)^2\,dx_i$ but now the mean has changed so you need $\int (x_i-\mu')^2\,dx_i$  where $\mu'=\sum p_i\mu_i$.  Like I say, do it for a blend of a couple discrete distributions (so these are simple sums instead of integrals) and you'll see how it plays out.

Comment: Should say: you can do the same thing via your approach  We know $E[(X_i-\mu_i)^2]$ and you want $E[(X_i-\mu')^2]$.  These two approaches are more or less equivalent.

Comment: @lulu Sorry but why wouldn't it be $\int_a^b (x_i-\mu')f(x) dx$?

Comment: By $dx_i$ I mean the probability measure attached to the random variable $X_i$.